# AngularJS: Display SVG from JSON

Tags: angularjs, svg

I want to display my svg file from json using Rest Api, I have not managed to display  it.

json file:

```
{
  "id": "sample string 1",
  "svg": "/PlanSvg/Planwidget",
  "name": "plan"
}
```

Controller.js:

```
$scope.LoadLeaf = function (Id_Leaf) {
    REST.DoGET(PATH_LEAF, "/" + Id_Leaf).success(function (data) {
        $scope.Leaf = data;

    }).error(function () {

    });
}
<div ng-controller="MapLiveWidget">
    <div >{{Leaf.id}}</div>
    <div>{{Leaf.name}}</div>
    <div><img ng-src="Leaf.svg'"</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you getting the SVG data back in the consol log? if so can you also include the svg data I can show how you can include it dynamically in the view from there.

Comment: Hello , in console log i don't succeeded to get Svg Data , i succeeded to get just the path : "/PlanSvg/Planwidget". Have you an idea please

Comment: Not clear what you're asking for here then, have you looked in the debug panel to see if the request is made and fails to load a response for some reason?  If not check out the network panel and see what's happening or not happening.

Comment: 404 just means the path/url is wrong or the server can't find a matching resource, is this a file you're trying to load from a local server? also looks like you have PlanSvg twice in that path is that an issue?

Comment: Yes  i try to load svg file from my desktop. i have this error :
 GET http://localhost:53708/PlanSvg/widgetPlan.svg 404 (Not Found

Comment: sounds so far like it's just a server configuration issue, which server are you using and how have you configured it so far? or rather how are you running the site/app right now (what is on port 53708 that should be serving up this file)

Comment: i'm using my local server and i get the svg file path from json via RestApi.
my svg file is on my desktop. and i want to load him in html page
 the port is 53708

Comment: GET http://localhost:53708/PlanSvg/widgetPlan.svg 404 (Not Found)